# C++ Cross-compiling to Windows from project on Ubuntu: Getting compiler errors about missing standard libraries

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, cross-compiling, crow

I'm new C++ and I'm trying to develop a very simple webserver app for Windows, but I'm compiling it on Ubuntu 22.04 using MinGW. All the versions of everything are the ones Ubuntu 22.04 will give to me with the latest updates from its default repositories.

I can compile it perfectly fine on Ubuntu: `g++ -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp -lcrypto -lpthread -I./Crow/include -I./json/include -I./tinyfiledialogs ./tinyfiledialogs/tinyfiledialogs.c -I./asio/include`

However, if I try to compile it targeting Windows with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -std=c++17 -o main.exe main.cpp -lws2_32 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lcrypto -lpthread -I./Crow/include -I./json/include -I./tinyfiledialogs ./tinyfiledialogs/tinyfiledialogs.c -I./asio/include`

I get a million errors that all look like this:

```
In file included from ./Crow/include/crow.h:15,
                 from main.cpp:13:
./Crow/include/crow/websocket.h: In destructor ‘crow::websocket::Connection<Adaptor, Handler>::~Connection()’:
./Crow/include/crow/websocket.h:132:26: error: ‘std::this_thread’ has not been declared
  132 |                     std::this_thread::yield();
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./Crow/include/crow.h:24,
                 from main.cpp:13:
./Crow/include/crow/http_server.h: At global scope:
./Crow/include/crow/http_server.h:268:14: error: ‘condition_variable’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
  268 |         std::condition_variable cv_started_;
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./Crow/include/crow.h:24,
                 from main.cpp:13:
./Crow/include/crow/http_server.h:21:1: note: ‘std::condition_variable’ is defined in header ‘<condition_variable>’; did you forget to ‘#include <condition_variable>’?
   20 | #include "crow/version.h"
  +++ |+#include <condition_variable>
   21 | #include "crow/http_connection.h"
In file included from ./Crow/include/crow.h:24,
                 from main.cpp:13:
./Crow/include/crow/http_server.h:269:14: error: ‘mutex’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
  269 |         std::mutex start_mutex_;
```

ChatGPT is insistent that the error is because the #include is missing from various files, but that is not true. I opened the files and the #include lines are indeed there.

I had exactly the same issue replacing Crow with httplib instead. I've also tried changing `c++17` to 11 or emitting it entirely - no difference.

How can I compile my very simple app targeting Windows?

Minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <crow.h>

int main() {
    crow::SimpleApp app;

    CROW_ROUTE(app, "/")
    ([]() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    });

    app.port(8080).multithreaded().run();
}
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253274/discussion-on-question-by-alasdair-c-cross-compiling-to-windows-from-project-o); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by using `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++` when it should instead be `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-posix`.